# When using jQuery contextMenu with custom activated menus, how do I change the position of the menu?

Tags: jquery, position, contextmenu

I'm using jquery contextMenu for drop down menus.  I'm not really using the right-click functionality.  Instead, when I click on a div tag, the menu appears below that div tag.  That much I have working.  Here's the demo page from which I based my code: http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/trigger-custom.html.

What I'd like to do is offset the position of the drop down menu relative to its default position.  In the demo linked to above, you'll see that one example is:

```
$('#activate-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.context-menu-one').contextMenu({x: 100, y: 100}); 
})
```

This hasn't worked for me.  The menu appears way up at the top left of my browser instead of being offset from the position where it normally would appear.

Thanks for any help!

Bret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that plug-in, but it sounds like the `x` and `y` options are relative to the document (or possibly the element identified by the selector, [the documentation](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#show-trigger) seems a bit vague). The [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) you receive on the click has `pageX` and `pageY` properties which tell you where the click occurred relative to the document, so just add to those, e.g.:

```
$('.context-menu-one').contextMenu({
    x: e.pageX + 100,
    y: e.pageY + 100
});
```

Offsetting by 100 pixels may be a bit much, but that's the principle.

Comment: Exellent!  That did the trick perfectly.  Thanks T.J.  I agree that the documentation is a little strange.  For others: If you're going to set the position this way, it's important to set both x and y.  When I only set x, I ran into problems.